# Windows robust check if VirtualBox is installed

Tags: windows, command-line, virtualbox

I need to automate installing `Virtualbox` if it is not already installed on a `Windows` host.

Installing `VirtualBox` does not seem to add it to the `Environment Path`,checking with `where`  below does not work. Is there a robust way to check if VirtualBox is installed on Windows?

Either a shell command or `bat` script is acceptable.

```
$ where VirtualBox
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Is there a robust way to check if VirtualBox is installed on Windows?

> All the the following only apply to official builds of VirtualBox. If
> you're dealing with a custom/OSE build, then all bets are off.
>
> - On Windows: There should be at least one of the two environment variables:
>
>   ```
>   VBOX_INSTALL_PATH
>   VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH
>   ```
> - On Linux, You can:
>
>   - Check for the existence of the virtualbox driver, located at `/dev/vboxdrv`
>   - Check for symlinks to the virtualbox executables in the `PATH`, or simply check if well-knowns executable exists in
>     `/usr/lib/virtualbox`, like `VirtualBox`, `VBoxManage`, `vboxwebsrv`
> - On OSX, check for VirtualBox executable in `/usr/local/bin`
>
> Source: [virtualbox.org • View topic - How to know if VirtualBox is
> installed using
> APIs](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=80929)

Comment: You can also simply check for the registry key.  First, do `reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Oracle\VirtualBox|findstr -si InstallDir` then check the result of that call `if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 echo VirtualBox is installed`

Comment: Also, @DavidPostill , his `where VirtualBox` would have been fine on the other two platforms.  Your answer was certainly better which is why i didn't post one.  I'm just sayin'